# My scss/css is repeating class

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

Please, help me.
Someone could tell why my scss/css is repeating class. This make my browser be so slow.

Im using: Reactjs, Webpack, Sass structure (Assets folder).

[image: Css repeating class]

Comment: You're loading your bundle.js multiple times

Comment: Wow, thank you. thank you. thank you. XD

Comment: @Gerardo You should post your comment as an answer so that Ismael can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the CSS, you could have the same class many times and that wouldn't affect the performance... You're calling `bundle.js` multiple times and since it's a bundle it contains a lot of Javascript code and that off course is gonna slow down your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem removing the 'bundle.js' calling in my 'index.html' file.